# 2^1000 is a constant function or exponential function

Tags: time-complexity

As the title said, my problem is to know whether 2^1000 is a constant or exponential function.

I think it's constant as there are no dependant variable n. But it almost looks like 2^n ,like the exponential function.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it has an exponent (that's different than exponential, i.e. O(2^n)!), if there's no variable like `n` then it can't be anything but constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets denote the function as T(n) = 2^1000.

Does T(n) value change with different values of n? No.
If for every domain value of T the result is the same then T is a constant function.

Other way to realize the question answer is to find the range of the function. If it contains only one element then such function is a constant function.